# Do you have to add the attribute of another entity if it's a foreign key?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I'm making an ER model for a fictive zoo. I have an entity named "Tickets" which has a an ID_key and the attribute "Type_of_ticket". I made another entity called "Prices" which contains the type of tickets and the prices and is in a relation to Tickets. Do I have to add the attribute "Type_of_ticket" to the Price entity? Or is the "Price" attribute on its own enough?

Answer (score 0):

If your "Price" entity includes only price itself, it would be better to add Price as an attribute to the Tickets entity instead of having two separate entities.

At the end, "Tickets" entity would have attributes: Id_Key, a string "Type_of_ticket" and a decimal(12,2) "Price".

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. In the Price entity I actually also have another attribute called Age_limit. Would it then be necessary to add the Type_of_ticket attribute to the Price entity?


In hindsight, it might be better to rename the Price entity to Ticket_Information.

Comment: If that is the case, you have two options I believe:
1. Merge all attributes in one table like I suggested at first.

If however, you want to keep two entities in order to extend it later on, then you must include Ticket_ID_key inside the "Price" entity as a foreign key. 
Remember, it is good practice to have a primary key be a foreign key. 
You can then acquire the other attributes by joining the two tables based on Ticket_ID_key